# Is there any reason for using WebGL instead of 2D Canvas for 2D games/apps?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, webgl

Is there any reason, except performance, for using WebGL instead of 2D-Canvas for **2D** games/apps?

In other word what 2D functionalities are offered by WebGL which are not possible to achieve easily with 2D-Canvas?

Comment: By the way: While you can't use the 2d and the 3d context API on the same canvas, you can still combine them by using multiple canvases. WebGL can use 2d canvases as textures and 2d canvases can use WebGL canvases as sources for drawImage.

Comment: For a few more details on @Philipp's comment see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016197/1804173).

Comment: Because WebGL can be faster. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867297/why-webgl-is-faster-than-canvas

Answer (score 159):

Looking at this question from another side:
How does a developer choose one technology over another?

- integrates better in their already built system
- is easier to use
- is faster
- has more capabilities or better suits their needs
- cost
- more platform-independent

So I'll discuss the differences between canvas and webGL APIs regarding these qualities.

---

Both canvas and webGL are JavaScript APIs. They are pretty much the same regarding integration (binding). They are both supported by a number of libraries that could speed up your coding. Different libraries give you different ways to organize your code, so library choice dictates how your drawing APIs are structured, but it's still pretty much the same thing (how the rest of the code binds together with it). If you use library, the ease of writing code depends on the library itself.

If you write code from zero, the canvas API is much easier to learn and understand. It requires minimal math knowledge, and development is fast and straightforward.

Working with the WebGL API requires strong math skills and a full understanding of the rendering pipeline. People with these skills are harder to find, production is slower (due to the size and complexity of such a code base), and therefore it costs more.

WebGL is faster and it has more capabilities. No doubt about that. It's a native 3D API that gives you full access to the rendering pipeline, code and effects are executed faster and are more 'tweakable'. With webGL there really is no limit.

Both canvas and webGL are html5 goodies. Usually the devices that support one will support and the other.

So, to sum up:

- merging the drawing API code and the rest (integration): similar
- ease of use:
- (with library) canvas = webGL
- (from scratch) webGL << canvas
- speed: webGL > canvas
- capabilities: webGL > canvas
- cost: webGL is much more expensive
- platform: very similar

P. S. Open for discussion.

Comment: @Abstract, Where are good tutorials for web GL and how many hours will it take?

Comment: @Pacerier just google it, first few hits are probably good enough. However, it will take weeks and months to get good at webgl and graphics programming in general, and years to be really good. It's not just some random "library" that you need to learn API for and that's it.

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm, I mean if you're alr a master with programming canvas , how many hours will switching to web GL take?

Comment: @Pacerier that depends on the dev and as Abstract already said the math skills of the dev involved. There really isn't a quantification that can be made.

Comment: thanks for this comparison. any updates in 2021, or do you believe this analysis still holds?

Comment: @Crashalot It holds up pretty well. Canvas is still an easier API for mostly CPU drawing, and webGL/webGPU is a fully exposed GPU drawing API - you can control it more and make it faster, but you pay the price in dev time probably and required knowledge.

Answer (score 49):

The biggest advantage is the programmability of the pipeline, and the performance. For example, say you are drawing 2 boxes one above other and one is hidden, some GL implementations have scope for discarding the hidden box.

Comparison table below. Added Three.js for completeness only.

| Canvas API | WebGL Equivalent | Three.js Framework Equivalent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| scale | texImage2D + modify vertices | Camera |
| rotate | texImage2D + modify vertices | Camera |
| translate | texImage2D + modify vertices | Camera |
| transform | texImage2D + modify vertices | Camera |
| clearRect | clear + viewport, or texImage2d | Textures |
| fillRect | clear + viewport, or texImage2d | Textures |
| strokeRect | texImage2d | Textures |
| path | texImage2d + stencil+ vertex paths | Camera + objects |
| fillText | texImage2d + stencil+ vertex paths | Camera + objects + textures |
| strokeText | texImage2d + stencil+ vertex paths | Camera + objects + textures |
| drawImage | texImage2d | Textures |
| createImageData | fill buffer of texImage2d in CPU application | CPU application code |
| getImageData | readpixels | readpixels |
| putImageData | fill buffer of texImage2d in CPU application | fill buffer of texImage2d in CPU application |
|  | + programmable shaders (vertex,fragment) |  |
|  | + offscreen buffers |  |
|  | + efficient 3D representation of depth |  |
|  | + efficient points (and other primitive) rendering |  |
|  |  | + Convenience methods - Materials (sprite ..) |
|  |  | + Convenience methods - Lights |
|  |  | + Convenience methods - Scenes |

Comment: Re "some GL implementations have scope for discarding the hidden box" but couldn't you detect that overridden part in JS and thus not redraw what's not needed?

Comment: Now that tables are supported in SO markdown, would you care to update this?

Answer (score 23):

Speaking from experience on my own applications, graphics shaders have been the one and only reason I've required support for WebGL. Ease of use has little bearing for me since both frameworks can be abstracted away with three.js. Assuming I don't need shaders, I allow use of either framework to maximize browser/machine support.

Answer (score 19):

What 2D capability does WebGL offer that 2D canvas does not?  The biggest one IMHO is the programmable fragment shaders on the graphics hardware.  For example, in WebGL, one can implement Conway's Game of Life in a shader on your 3D hardware:

http://glslsandbox.com/e#207.3

This kind of 2D display would only run on the CPU, not the GPU, with a 2D canvas.  All of the computations would be implemented in JavaScript, and would not be as parallel as the GPU even with the help of web workers.  This is just one example of course, all kinds of interesting 2D effects can be implemented with shaders.

Comment: Thus vs canvas, is WebGL more or less taxing on the OS?

Comment: I'm curious whether all canvas ends up doing webgl anyway; if it uses precompiled common use case webgl, which would be more efficient than direct webgl; or if it's not interfacing with opengl in any way unless you use webgl.

Comment: @Dmitry great question, and different browsers are free to take different approaches to that problem.  But, no matter how they accelerate the Canvas 2D API, the Canvas 2D API itself doesn't offer programmable shaders or vertex array buffers.  It's a "chatty" API (one JavaScript-to-Native call per element drawn), whereas WebGL's API allows bulk data loading and GPU-based custom processing.

Answer (score 17):

Well, performance would be the one of the biggest reasons because when you are coding a game, it has to be fast. But there are a couple of other reasons for which you might want to choose WebGL over canvas. It offers the possibility to coding shaders, lighting and zooming, which is important if you are doing a commercial game app. Also canvas gets laggy after 50 sprites or so.

Comment: Especially on a device like an android tablet where the CPU gets overloaded quick in javascript, the main reason to use WebGL is to transfer the rendering load onto the GPU.

Comment: @Xk0n, Re "fers the possibility to coding shaders, lighting and zooming", But then doesn't it become GPU-dependent?

Comment: You can still zoom with setTransform in a 2D canvas context. I've been having a hard time with texture bleeding in 2D canvas when scaling from sprite sheets, however, which is why I'm turning to WebGL. I saw a tutorial that stops the nearest neighbor sampling from going outside of the source rect, which should fix my bleeding edge problem.

Comment: After 50? Yikes, I was about to do tens of thousands of tiles...

Comment: @Xk0nSid can you please expand on "Also canvas gets laggy after 50 sprites or so." do you have a link to back this up?

Comment: Id say it doesn't get laggy until about 120 sprites, but then again I am 2 years later to this and using a brand new computer... So maybe that is just technology advancements.

Answer (score 12):

There's nothing you can do with Canvas that you can't also do with WebGL: the canvas lets you crush the bytes with get/putImageData, and you can draw lines, circles, ... programmatically with WebGL.

If you're seeking to do intensive drawing, such as complex effects at 60 fps, the performance gap is high. Things that are really slow with 2D Canvas will run fine in WebGL. Performance is WebGL's basic feature.

Yet WebGL is quite complicated to program. See if canvas is good enough for you, or seek a library that will ease the pain.

Another drawback to WebGL: it doesn't work on IE (but what does?), and on some mobile platforms. See here for compatibility: https://caniuse.com/webgl

Comment: any updates on this opinion for 2021 (besides widespread compatibility for webgl now)? thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 9):

As you specifically want some classic 2d things that don't work well with canvas:

- color transforms (like blinking a sprite)
- repeating bitmap fills
- tiling maps under rotation (under canvas some implementations will create seams)
- deep layering (very implementation dependent)
- multiplicative or additive blending

... but of course you have pixel access, so you can do really anything, including the above, manually. But that can be really, really slow. You could emscripten Mesa openGl to render to canvas in theory.

Another big reason to use webGL would be that the result is very easy to port to anywhere else. Which also makes the skill more valuable.

Reasons to use canvas are that it is still better supported and if you learn doing things pixel by pixel that is also a very valuable lesson.

Comment: Btw Is WebGL multithreaded? Can you have two threads drawing two parts of the screen concurrently?

Comment: I think that the answer is "yes and no," since web browsers are inherently single-threaded, so copying the data to be rendered to the GPU is not multi-threaded. But, you are using the massive parallelization of the graphics card once the shaders start rendering, which is essentially drawing to multiple parts of the screen at once. Please correct me if I'm wrong, anyone.

Comment: thanks for sharing. do you think this analysis is still true in 2021?

Answer (score 3):

As WebGL is particularly new technology and HTML5 canvas is more established what you want to use depends on your users. If you think that your users will use mobile devices then I would suggest HTML5 canvas but if you want better 2D rendering I would use WebGL. So what you could do is if the use is on mobile render with HTML5 else if they are on a platform that supports WebGL.

For example:

```
 if (window.WebGLRenderingContext) {
     webGLcanvasApp()
         } else if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     html5CanvasAppFMobile()
    } else {
    html5CanvasApp()
    }
```

Sources:
[Proper way to detect WebGL support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871077/proper-way-to-detect-webgl-support)
[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

WebGL is unusable* (see comments) without a GPU.
This hardware dependency is not a big problem because most systems have GPUs, but if GPU or CPU architectures ever evolve, preserving webgl content by emulation may be challenging. Running it on old (virtualized) computers is problematic.

But "Canvas vs WebGL" does not have to be a binary choice.
I actually prefer using webgl for effects, but doing the rest in canvas.
When I run it in a VM, it still works nicely and fast, just without the effects.

Update: Unfortunatelly some browsers ([Chrome on Windows](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/SwiftShader-brings-software-3D-rendering-to-Chrome), [Everything on Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_%28computer_graphics%29), others?) implement well-meant emulation layers [that make detection of poor/no GPUs hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456491/detect-swiftshader-webgl-renderer-in-chrome-18). In these cases either the game or the user has to disable WebGL manually to get the actual performance benefits...
...or degradation, when the 2D is implemented poorly. Allegedly that can happen too. [Thanks gman]

Comment: This is untrue. [Chrome has run WebGL in software on systems without GPU for the last 8 years](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/SwiftShader-brings-software-3D-rendering-to-Chrome).

Comment: Quoting the page: "The performance of SwiftShader should be good enough to view simple 3D content". "Working", but unusable for games. @gman

Comment: Correct, but this "WebGL is unusable without a GPU" is false. It might be slow but it is not unusable. if it was unusable without a GPU there would be no reason for a solution to use it without a GPU to even exist in Chrome.

Comment: Surprisingly many games are designed for 100% FPS and break when you have no physical GPU.

Comment: You know that Swiftshader was written by a company [to port games to systems without a GPU](https://www.gamesindustry.biz/transgaming-launches-swiftshader-the-worlds-fastest-shader-enabled-3d-rendering-software)? In any case, my point wasn't to say emulation is fast enough for your use case. Even with hardware GPUs they might be too slow. I just tested a Samsung Galaxy J5 and even with a GPU it could barely spin a single cube at 10fps. So, this isn't about emulation vs non-emulation. It's about too slow for your needs vs not too slow.

Comment: @gman My point wasn't to say swiftshader is useless, but for games (especially in Unity3D) I often see fails in game logic because assumed FPS. Also I see way too many platforming games (->actually 2D) which would run much more efficiently if done in canvas with (optional) WebGL effects. I strongly believe this gives best from both worlds.